# Forwarding gmail into salesforce

Tags: gmail, salesforce

Is there a way to get error messages from gmail that show success rate of forwarded messages?? Answer provided by googling and going through google admin was not correct. I am sending mails from Gmail into salesforce and for reasons unknown not all of them are received by salesforce

I need to see how are emails forwarded into another email, if correctly